# C++ libcurl upload progress bar

Tags: c++, upload, progress-bar, libcurl

it's simple: we are uploading HUGE files to online data storage using libcurl easy interface.
I need to show the progress of this upload. I know all fileinfo, so basically i have to find out how many bits/bytes had been sent and calculate the persentage from whole file.

I looked throught libcurl manuals, but I've not found any information about upload progress, only for download progress.

I'm new with libcurl and i'm using colleague's funcs. So i might missed something.

Is there a method for monitor upload progress using **libcurl**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check their [documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html):

> For historical and traditional reasons, libcurl has a built-in
>   progress meter that can be switched on and then makes it present a
>   progress meter in your terminal.
>
> Switch on the progress meter by, oddly enough, setting
>   `CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS` to zero. This option is set to `1` by default.
>
> For most applications however, the built-in progress meter is useless
>   and what instead is interesting is the ability to specify a progress
>   callback. The function pointer you pass to `libcurl` will then be called
>   on irregular intervals with information about the current transfer.
>
> Set the progress callback by using `CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION`. And pass
>   a pointer to a function that matches this prototype:

```
  int progress_callback(void *clientp,
                        double dltotal,
                        double dlnow,
                        double ultotal,
                        double ulnow);
```

> If any of the input arguments is unknown, a 0 will be passed. The
>   first argument, the 'clientp' is the pointer you pass to libcurl with
>   `CURLOPT_PROGRESSDATA`. libcurl won't touch it.

Comment: Just note: "We encourage users to use the newer CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION instead, if you can. "